# display two woocommerce categories on front page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have two categories called mobile and laptop, which I want to show both at the same time on the main page. I used this code but it only shows one of the categories. Thank you for your help

```
  <?php $products= new WP_Query(
 array(
     'post_type'=>'product',
     'posts_per_page'=>'-1',
     'product_cat' => 'mobile+laptop',
     'orderby' => 'rand',
    
 )
 ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tax_query`. try the below code.

```
<?php 
$products = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'mobile'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'laptop'
            )
        ),
    ) 
); 
?>
```